# How to know which figure I clicked?

Tags: c#, graphics, linked-list

I have drawn an orthogonal linked list that looks like this.

:[image: orthogonal linked list]

And I want to know if I clicked INSIDE of any Node (rectangle) and tell me witch rectangle with a message box with the data or number that it has

The nodes are drawn with this method:

```
public void Dnode(float px, float py, int data)
    {
        Pen penBlack= new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        RectangleF[] rects =
        {
            new RectangleF(px, py, 50.0F, 50.0F), 
            new RectangleF(px + 10, py + 10, 30.0F, 30.0F)
        };
        G.DrawRectangles(penBlack, rects);
        G.DrawLine(penBlack, px, py, px + 10, py + 10);
        G.DrawLine(penBlack, px + 50, py, px + 40, py + 10);
        G.DrawLine(penBlack, px + 50, py + 50, px + 40, py + 40);
        G.DrawLine(penBlack, px, py + 50, px + 10, py + 40);
        if (data!= -1)
            G.DrawString(data.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,
                new Point((int) px + 16, (int) py + 14));
        else
            G.DrawString("*", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red,
                new Point((int) px + 19, (int) py + 18));
    }
```

every node has this

```
public class Node
{
    public int data;
    public int pointX, pointY;
    public Node left, right, up, down;

    public Node(int x)
    {
        data = x;
        left = right = up = down = null;
        pointX = 0;
        pointY = 0;
    }
}
```

The idea that I had was to get the point that I clicked with the click event in the main form and then compare it with every node of the list but then I realized it will only work if I clicked the specific point that the node class has

Comment: Maybe just create transparent objects (like labels?) and use onClick event, but the way of Andrei seems to be better with performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `bool isClicked(float x, float y)` method to the node class and see if the point with (x, y) coordinates falls into the square that was drawn for each node.

For that, x and y need to respect **all** the following conditions:

- x >= px; x <= px + 50.0F
- y >= py; y <= py + 50.0F